# Variable Becomes Undefined in Last Iteration of Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a application where I am getting route info from one location to another, possibly between multiple locations. In my function, I'm looping over checked locations and writing out the directions to the page with jQuery. On the last iteration of the loop the 'myRoute' variable becomes undefined. So, if I have three locations, it bombs on the third, but if I use those same three and add a fourth, the first three works and the fourth bombs. I traced the behavior in Firebug, and while the myRoute variable does get filled properly, as soon as it moves to the next line, it is all of a sudden undefined. I removed instances of `myRoute` and replaced with `directionResult.routes[0].legs[i]` but still got the undefined error. What's going on here?

```
function setInstructions(directionResult, idname, start) {
//clean tour list
$('#tours_list .tour').remove();
$('#routeTitle').show();
var checkboxArray = $(".selector.Favs" + idname).find("li");
var idx = 0;

var linkMap = $('#routeTitle').find('.link-map')[0];
linkMap.href = __mapLink+'saddr=' + start;
var firstStop = true;
//iterate selected properties
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    var curChk = checkboxArray[i];
    if ($(curChk).hasClass('active')) {        
        //get steps
        var myRoute = directionResult.routes[0].legs[i]; //this is what becomes undfined
        var title = $('<div>').addClass('mileage').append($('<p>').append($('<strong>').html(myRoute.distance.text + "<br /> about " + myRoute.duration.text)));
        var ol = $('<ol>').addClass('directions');
        for (var j = 0; j < myRoute.steps.length; j++) {
            var step = myRoute.steps[j];
            var li = $('<li>').append($('<div>').addClass('direction').html(step.instructions));
            li.append($('<div>').addClass('distance').html(step.distance.text + " - " + step.duration.text));
            ol.append(li);
        }                      
        //add tour with directions
        $('#tours_list').append(temp);          
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The obvious question is this `directionResult.routes[0].legs[i]`.  How many items are in `directionResult.routes[0].legs`?  If there are fewer than `checkboxArray.length`, that would explain why you get `undefined` at the end of the loop.

Comment: There's more in checkboxArray, but the variable is only instantiated if the item has a class of Active. If I expect 3 (3 items are selected), the if statement is true three times as expected. I set a breakpoint and the third time, myRoute has the correct data in it, but when I step down to where title is set, myRoute is all of a sudden undefined.

Comment: That's because the array at `directionResult.routes[0].legs` doesn't have enough items in it - it is too short.  When you step down to the line where the title is set, that's when myRoute is set in this iteration (the debugger has not yet executed the line that is selected).  Add a `console.log(directionResult.routes[0].legs.length)` to see how long it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the array in `directionResult.routes[0].legs` is not as long as `checkboxArray.length` so your code is trying to access beyond the end of `directionResult.routes[0].legs` and thus gets `undefined`.

It isn't helping you that you are testing for only active class items because `i` goes from 0 to `checkboxArray.length - 1` regardless.

---

I don't follow exactly what you're trying to do, but you might be able to work around this by only iterating the items that have .active in the first place so `i` never goes beyond the number of active items.  You might be able to do that by changing this:

```
var checkboxArray = $(".selector.Favs" + idname).find("li");
```

to this:

```
var checkboxArray = $(".selector.Favs" + idname).find("li.active");
```

And, then remove the `if` check for the active class.  This will make it so your index `i` never goes higher than the number of active items.

---

You could also just keep a counter of the active items you've processed and use that counter to index into `directionResult.routes[0].legs[cntr]` instead of using `i`.

Comment: You put me in the right direction in your comments above. I subtracted 1 from i and got the proper results but then got the same idea to just get the matching list items. Thanks for your help with this!